# Host website during integration test

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, integration-testing

I'm working on a scraper for which I'm trying to write an integration test that scrapes HTML that's stored on disk. The test should scrape image urls from img src. In the code, this boils down to `Jsoup.connect(url)` where url is a String. I know about mocking but that doesn't belong in an integration test. That's the reason I think hosting the site, and really return an image is the way to go. Other options are welcome of course.

Ideally, a small footprint web server starts up when the test runs. I should be able to determine or at least know the url on which it publishes the site. I should also be able to point the web server to a HTML file.

The scraper project is a Spring Boot. I can serve the page statically, as in from /static, not resolved by a controller. When I have a controller return the page, it's resolved by Thymeleaf and it throws `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference`. To see these results, I run the whole Spring Boot application.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using **WireMock** (http://wiremock.org/) in your case. WireMock helps you running HTTP server and stubbing its behavior in the integration (or unit) tests environment. Take a look at following example (JUnit test):

```
package com.github.wololock;

import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit.WireMockRule;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.aResponse;
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.get;
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.urlEqualTo;
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.options;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

public final class WireMockHtmlTest {

    @Rule
    public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(options().port(8080));

    @Before
    public void setup() throws IOException {
        final InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("html/index.html");
        final String html = new String(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        wireMockRule.stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/index"))
                    .willReturn(aResponse()
                            .withBody(html)
                            .withHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8")
                    )
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        //given:
        final URLConnection connection = new URL("http://localhost:8080/index").openConnection();
        //when:
        final String body = IOUtils.toString(connection.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        //then:
        assertThat(body.contains("Hello world!"), is(equalTo(true)));
    }
}
```

This test loads content of HTML file stored in `src/test/resources/html/index.html`, this file contains:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello world!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

There are just a few things you need to do if you want to use WireMock in your integration test:

1. Specify `@Rule` with `WireMockRule` (it handles running HTTP server). One thing worth mentioning - use a port number that is not in use, otherwise server wont start.
2. Stub server behavior in `@Before` phase (you can find more about stubbing here - http://wiremock.org/docs/stubbing/)
3. Prepare a test case that connects to the server running (on `localhost`).
4. You don't have to worry about shutting down the HTTP server - it will get shutdown when running test is completed.

I've pasted all imports on purpose so you can see which classes were used.

- WireMock 2.6.0 (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.tomakehurst/wiremock/2.6.0)
- Apache Commons-IO 2.4 (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.4)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I used your suggestion to mock a response for the calls to the urls in <img src="...">. I made some edits to your code to get it working: aResponse().withBody(img).withHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg"). The img argument is a byte array in this case. WireMock is definitely usable in my project, ty. I will mark it as answer if no better answer rolls in.